# What is the negation of k(k+1)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The original question is to prove that the product of any two consecutive integers is even.

I can do this using direct proof: P implies Q.

I was curious to try to prove it by contraposition (not Q implies not P), but in order to do that i need to negate "the product of any two consecutive integers", which I couldn't find out how to do.
Any help would be great. (first time posting so tell if I am doing anything wrong :)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is: assume that the product is odd and show  that the integers cannot be consecutive

Comment: Also there is an easier way to prove this by just considering the case of even and odd numbers and knowing that odd times even is even.

Comment: Awesome!!! You guy rock! I did not expect such fast and effective answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of "Every product of two consecutive integers is even" is "There exists two consecutive integers whose product is odd".

Comment: This is the negation, but the OP asks for the contrapositive, which is different.

Comment: The OP asks for both a negation so they can find a contrapostive.

Comment: What "both" did you negate? It seems to me you negated the entire implication at once.

Comment: @DavidK Typo there shouldn't be a "both" in there.

Comment: OK, but a contrapositive requires the negations of two separate statements. Which two statements did your answer negate, and how did you negate them?

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase the statement as follows:

> If $n$ is the product of two consecutive integers, then $n$ is even.

So $P$ is "$n$ is the product of two consecutive integers"
and $Q$ is "$n$ is even."
Therefore the contrapositive, $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P,$ is

> If $n$ is not even then $n$ is not the product of two consecutive integers.

To do this a little more formally we should quantify $n,$
"for all $n$," or perhaps more specifically "for every integer $n$."